# NewLine and Carriage Return in File failing to parse in Polybase

Tags: newline, carriage-return, polybase

Recently i run into this trouble. I have exported the data from a system using data factory and saved it as txt files in blob storage. We I tread reading from Azure data warehouse using polybase, the reading failing due to new line and carriage return ins come text columns.

at the moment Polybase can not handle this and the import will fail.

I generated loads of text files from RDBM for each file and I cannot find and replace in  each columns of the tables and I wonder after generating the file in blob if there is a way to find and replace new line and Carriage returns inside a column.

Or is there any other better solution or work around to this issue?

thanks